# The rationale for using a lagged variable to address endogeneity arising from simultaneous causation?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, economic-growth, endogeneity

when there is simultaneous causation  between  dependent and  independent variables often in papers we see a  lagged  variable being  used in place of contemporaneous variable. For  example,  Clemens,   Radelet,  Bhavnani  and  Bazzi  (2012)  say - “We  avoid  poor-quality  instrumental variables and instead address  potential  biases from   reverse  and  simultaneous  causation  by  the   more   transparent   method  of  lagging".   Hayo,  Kutan,  and   Neuenkirch  (2010)  - “The  vector  of  controls  contains  lagged    returns...Contemporaneous  U.S.  returns  are  excluded  to  avoid    simultaneity  problems”  However what is the rationale for lagging? This  short article   looks at estimators of lagged variables used in such  cases. It  deduces  that either there is no serial correlation in the  variable and  the  value of the lagged estimator is 0. Or that there is  serial   correlation and the value of the lagged estimator is quite a meaningless value of  ((c+bf)/(1-be)), where b is the coefficient of x(t)  on y(t), f is the serial correlation, e is the effect of y(t) on x(t) and c is the true effect of x(t-1) on y(t). Further the article finds that these estimators are consistent but converge to true value  only for n>100 approximately, further leading to wrong significance interpretations. Given this,   what is the rationale of  using a lag to deal with simultaneity? If the lagged  variable is not serially  correlated its  coefficient on y(t) is 0,   it does not capture the  effect of x(t) on y(t) and one only risks to make false significance inferences in small samples. If on the   other hand the variable is  serially correlated than it does capture the   effect of x(t) on y(t), but  only by the fraction of serial correlation and further that result  is distorted in non linear way because  the  estimator also captures the  effect of 1 - (y(t) on x(t) times x(t) on y(t)) in the denominator. So it is just a   meaningless result. Henceforth,  why do people use the lagged  variables  to address simultaneity  endogeneity? It seems to make no  sense.

The aforementioned article is this one: https://www.otago.ac.nz/economics/news/otago075947111111111.pdf

Your thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Hi: I only glanced at the paper and In not well versed in simultaneity bias but it sounds like an important finding which should be in a well known respected journal. If that is not the case, then the result is either incorrect or already well known. So, your best best is to ask an econometrics professor who is an expert in simultaneity bias and ask them what they think of the result. I would think something like that would have been discovered before ?